# Java regex to rewrite date expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a string with dates mentioned with "or" operator. I want to rewrite it with a "between" operator.
input :

```
 WHERE   table.it='2013-03-06-23'  OR  table.it='2013-03-07-00'  OR   table.it='2013-03-07-01'   OR   table.it='2013-03-07-02'   OR   table.it='2013-03-07-03'   OR   table.it='2013-03-07-04'   OR   table.it='2013-03-07-05'   OR   table.it='2013-03-07-06'  and table.name = 'test'
```

output :

```
 WHERE   table.it between '2013-03-06-23' and '2013-03-07-06' and table.name = 'test'
```

I want to rewrite it with first and last date with a between operator. 
Please advice how I can do it in java.

Thank You.

Comment: Why not create the WHERE clause correctly in the first place? Where does it come from? It is always better not to make a mistake than to repair it afterwards.

Comment: Thank You. I am getting this as input from HQL(hiveQL) and rewriting it with SQL to execute in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
String s = "WHERE   table.it='2013-03-06-23'  OR  table.it='2013-03-07-00'  OR   table.it='2013-03-07-01'   OR   table.it='2013-03-07-02'   OR   table.it='2013-03-07-03'   OR   table.it='2013-03-07-04'   OR   table.it='2013-03-07-05'   OR   table.it='2013-03-07-06'  and table.name = 'test'";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
m.find();
String first = m.group(1);
String last="";  
while(m.find()){
  last = m.group(1);
}
s = "WHERE table.it between "+first+" and "+last+" table.name = 'test'";
```